# invariant principle ( the room problem )

Tags: discrete-mathematics

At first the room is empty, each minute, either one person enters or two persons leave (we control this operation).

After exactly one hour, can the room contain 50 people ?

I did many diagrams and in each case I get 51 or or some number of people in but never exactly 50, of course this is not a proof that it can't occur since I did not do all possible ways.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Hint.** Consider the number of persons in the room _modulo 3_.

Comment: To me the assumption that there are $60$ instants at which people enter or leave (which you must have applied to get $51$ as possible outcome) seems off by $1$. It happens at $0$, $1$ ,$2$,... $,59$ and $60$ minutes past the start; that's $61$ times (classical fencepost problem). This makes $49$ or $52$ valid options; you still cannot make $50$.

Comment: thansk for answer .is that just some intuition or legit proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the population is $p$ at some particular time.
A minut later the population will become $(p+1)-(p-2)=3$ this paddern will continue forever.
At any time $t$ the population will be congruent mod 3(by definition)
in other words the population is invariant mod 3. 
in one 60 minuts a possible scenario is to add 1 person each minut , making total of 60 persons.
Thus *all* possible outcomes in 60 mins must be congruent to 60 mod3.

But 50 is not , conclution it can't happen.

Comment: Very elegant solution thanks !

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence at all. After having a population of $p$ the population always becomes $3$? You want to say $p+1$ or $p-2$, not $(p+1)-(p-2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let x be the number of times in the hour that one person enters. Then 60-x is the number of times in the hour that 2 people leave. Hence, we need only solve the following equation:

$x - 2(60-x) = 50$

If no integer solutions exist, this is impossible.

Comment: I don't understand , can you please explain more?